# How to increase struct array size at runtime

Tags: c++, c

I have a structure and want to increase an array size whenever SendMessage function calls

```
struct MQStruct {
    wchar_t *serviceName; 
    int durability; 
    int msgType; 
    int msgHeader; 
    wchar_t *msgId; 
    wchar_t *payload; 
    int payloadSize; 
    int ttl; 
    int priority;
}MQStructObj[1];


int SendMessage(wchar_t *serviceName, int durability, int msgType, int msgHeader, wchar_t *msgId, wchar_t *payload, int payloadSize, int ttl, int priority) {

//Want to add one more array object and also preserve data of previous
MQStructObj[MAX+1]

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a `std::vector`.

Comment: This looks like a C question, is it?

Comment: and `std::wstring` instead of `wchar_t*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C you will have to deal with dynamic memory (i.e allocate the array using `malloc()`, then take care to call `free()` when you stop using it etc.) yourself, and possibly use `realloc()` to grow an allocation.

In C++ the problem is already solved for you and you have `std::vector`. You may call `push_back` to add elements dynamically to it.

Comment: `realloc()`, not `reallocate()` and `malloc()`, not `alloc()`.

Comment: And this is C and C++, not `c` or `c++`.

Comment: @kmkaplan that is why I answered what are the OP's options in either case. If there is way to improve the answer please say so and I will try to do it.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Sorry, I must have been unclear. I mean that the *typography* of the names C and C++ is wrong in your answer. You write them in lower case and with code-like font instead of upper case and normal font. You wrote `c` where it is supposed to be C and `c++` instead of C++. Just a minor nitpick anyways.